# Is having a mutable reference and a mutable pointer to the same region UB in Rust?

Tags: rust

I have a recursive structure such as:

```rust
struct Node<T> {
    children: Vec<Node>,
    content: Option<T>
}
```

I want my structure to not have any "dead branches" (multiple nodes leading to a `content` set to `None`). So while going through it, I want to keep in mind the last time there was more than one child in a node. The way I was about to handle it is [in this Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=27b7fd668b4393e0da5a75b69ca99281):

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Node<T> {
    children: Vec<Node<T>>,
    content: Option<T>
}

impl <T> Node<T> {
    fn remove_leftmost(&mut self) {
        // I have `node`, a single mutable reference to my data
        let mut node: &mut Node<T> = self;
        let mut last_crossroads = None;
        while !node.children.is_empty() {
            let mut ptr = std::ptr::null_mut();
            if node.children.len() > 1 {
                // Now I also have `ptr`, a mutable pointer to my data
                ptr = node;
            }
            // But then, I modify `node` so that it references another node
            node = &mut node.children[0];
            if !ptr.is_null() {
                // `ptr` now refers to something that has no mutable reference to it
                // So `last_crossroads` should be ok, becoming the only mutable
                // reference to the precedent node
                last_crossroads = Some(unsafe { ptr.as_mut() }.unwrap());
            }
        }
        if let Some(cross) = last_crossroads {
            cross.children.remove(0);
        } else {
            // Out of the scope of the question
            todo!();
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut node = Node {
        children: vec![
            Node {
                children: vec![
                    Node {
                        children: vec![
                            Node {
                                children: vec![],
                                content: Some(4)
                            }
                        ],
                        content: None
                    }
                ],
                content: None
            },
            Node {
                children: vec![],
                content: Some(2)
            }
        ],
        content: Some(1)
    };
    node.remove_leftmost();
    println!("{:?}", node);
}
```

I know that having multiple mutable references to the same region is Undefined Behaviour. Does that apply to mutable pointers too? And if it isn't UB, would it be the right way to do it?

Edit: According to Miri it seems to be Undefined Behaviour... Any idea how to work around the idea?

Comment: To try by yourself, you can write some driver code and execute it with miri (which is also availab\e on the playground).

Comment: @Finomnis The thing is I'm trying to implement a prefix tree of some sort, so a node can have an empty content. It's a minimal example, so I didn't include a `label` in the struct, but I actually have one in my code. (also I forgot to put Option<T> in the Playground, that was a mistake)

Comment: Might be relevant: https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html

Comment: Having a pointer and a reference to the same data is not undefined behavior per se, but having two `&mut` references (`last_crossroads`) to the same thing breaks the [pointer aliasing rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/reference/behavior-considered-undefined.html), so I would argue this is considered undefined behavior.

Comment: Either way, you completely bypass the borrow checker with it, so there's no compiler guarantee about undefined behavior in this function any more. For example: The `node` variable only gets destroyed at the end of the function, and there's a good chance that it will be a dangling reference after `cross.children.remove`.

Comment: @Finomnis Well Miri says undefined behavior, so I guess you're right... I guess I'll have to find another way...

Comment: Sadly, ownership situations like this one are hard to solve efficiently. Recursive datastructures in general suffer from this problem in Rust. That's why they are [kind of frowned upon](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/). In my experience, when working with them, recursive algorithms are the easiest way to solve ownership problems. Although recursive algorithms are also kind of frowned upon due to their tendency to consume a lot of stack memory.

Comment: @Finomnis The `cross.children.remove` would really be the end of my function though, so I wouldn't reuse `last_crossroads` nor `node` after this.

Comment: That was just an example of the little details you are having to think about when going down that path. The point is that the main reason why someone would use Rust is the compile time safety guarantees, so I'm kinda leaning towards that one should not bypass that. Of course there are situations where it is necessary, but I'm kind of on the fence whether your problem falls under that category. But that thought is going in an opinion-based direction, so I'll leave it with that.

Comment: Nitpick: `ptr.as_mut().unwrap()` is usually an antipattern. Prefer `&mut *ptr`. It is more efficient by not checking for null. The only case where you should prefer `ptr.as_mut().unwrap()` is when you want to panic in case the pointer is null. Note this does not make the pointer access safe, as it can still be dangling or freed. In your case, even better is to use `if let Some(v) = ptr.as_mut()` instead of `if !ptr.is_null()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is unsound because the moment you went via `node.children`, you invalidated all pointers from `node`.

Most of the times there is a violation of Stacked Borrows, you can fix it by adding more unsafety and more raw pointers:

```rust
fn remove_leftmost(&mut self) {
    let mut last_crossroads = None;
    unsafe {
        // I have `node`, a single mutable reference to my data
        let mut node: *mut Node<T> = self;
        while !(*node).children.is_empty() {
            let mut ptr = std::ptr::null_mut();
            if (*node).children.len() > 1 {
                // Now I also have `ptr`, a mutable pointer to my data
                ptr = node;
            }
            // But then, I modify `node` so that it references another node
            node = (*node).children.as_mut_ptr();
            if !ptr.is_null() {
                // `ptr` now refers to something that has no mutable reference to it
                // So `last_crossroads` should be ok, becoming the only mutable
                // reference to the precedent node
                last_crossroads = Some(ptr.as_mut().unwrap());
            }
        }
    }
    if let Some(cross) = last_crossroads {
        cross.children.remove(0);
    } else {
        // Out of the scope of the question
        todo!();
    }
}
```

But this probably isn't the right way. Unless your data structure is deep, the easiest way is to use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

It is safe to hold a raw pointer, `*const T` or `*mut T`, at the same time as a mutable reference, `&mut T`, to the same data. However, it is Undefined Behaviour if you deference that raw pointer while the mutable reference is still live.

In your code, the mutable reference, `node`, lives for the duration of the function but the raw pointer is converted into another mutable reference in `last_crossroads`. Since they are pointing to the same data, this is UB.

Writing unsafe code in Rust is really difficult. Ideally, try to avoid mixing the world of references and the world of pointers. Using both raw pointers and references mixed together in the same function can make it difficult to reason about.

Working with recursion is especially tricky because you need to know what's going on inside the functions you call, to make sure they don't take new references either.

Comment: But since `node` is modified before the pointer is dereferenced into `last_crossroads`, do the two really points to the same data? I understand that you could use `last_crossroads` to reach `node` once more, effectively creating a mutable reference alias, which would be UB. But as long as it's not used this way, isn't it supposed to be sound?

Comment: The way I'm perceiving it, the main problems are: pointing to the same data (which I'd say is not really the case since I won't go reach `node` with `last_crossroads`, but that's arguable), and dangling reference (but I don't need `node` after unpacking `last_crossroads`, so the reference will most likely be dropped before I `last_crossroads.children.remove`).

Comment: `last_crossroads` includes exclusive access to everything in `node` though. So you're violating the pointer aliasing guarantee that everything that could be reached by references derived from `last_crossroads` can only be reached by references derived from it. I.e. **safe** code could create the same pointer as `node` by `&mut last_crossroads.children[0]`, which is a bit more obviously aliasing, the indirection just makes it less obviously visible.

Comment: @cafce25 OK I see, thanks... But then, would it be considered unsafe (so that the "contract" to uphold would have a "do not use &mut last_crossroads.children[0]" clause), or would it be straight up UB? The thing is, I never need to use `&mut last_crossroads.children[0]`. Moreover, the [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/aliasing.html) says that "variables and pointers alias if they refer to overlapping regions of memory". Since I wouldn't index it, the regions of memory wouldn't be the same (although there is a way to reach `node` with `last_crossroads`)

Comment: No, the outer `node` is no the problem, since the pointer is derived from it (just like we're allowed in safe code to have multiple overlapping mutable references if they form a chain). The problem is that by going through `node` (the inner) you've invalidated the pointer.